# Test is not an annotation type

Tags: eclipse, maven, testng

in my **maven** project, i have added the **testng** dependency as below:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

But, then when i write a simple test as below, it cannot find `@Test` :

```
public class Test{


    @Test
    public void test() {

    }

}
```

it complains with `Test is not an annotation type`
i tried to add the test manually by the below line:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
```

but again it complains with:

```
The import org.testng.annotations.Test conflicts with a type defined in the same file
```

I have Forced Update my project by maven several times but still no success.

Comment: Does it help when you rename your class "Test" to e.g. "FooTest"?

Comment: unfortunately, No. it does not change anything.

Comment: The following code works for me: `import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    public class FooTest {

        @Test
        public void test() {

        }
    }`
with FooTest being in src/test/java and the maven dependency mentioned above added to my pom.

Comment: @Jeff everything seems to be correct. Infect I added the same dependency and works fine. I would suggest you retry it. Clean/Refresh project once done properly. You can also add jar directly and then retry.

Comment: If you must use `Test` as your class name change the annotation to FQN `@org.testng.annotations.Test`

Answer (score 5):

It is not working because your class name also the "Test" so, you have to change the class name then only @Test annotation will work.

Comment: Same problem here. It worked after changing the class name.

Answer (score 0):

Remove scope tag from respective dependency in pom.xml. It shall work.